What is a 受け身も取れず?

感情的な受け身も取れず、そりゃ大騒ぎもしますよ」

Googling around 受け身も取れず seems to be used to indicate this

誰かに攻撃的な言動や行動をされた時に、上手くかわすことが出来ない。

So he's saying "Without being able to skillfully dodging the issue"  But then why 攻撃的な being used?
For context, he's saying that a group of people who spent years ignoring an enemy, but then suddenly the enemy appeared and now everyone got news of it and everyone is panicking on what to do.

If your source is this, just ignore this page and look for a more generic explanation of the phrase.

受け身を取る refers to this basic martial arts technique used to absorb the impact when being physically thrown to the ground. This technique does not involve "dodging". If someone cannot even perform 受け身 (受け身も取れない), it means they have not even mastered the basics and are prone to injury. This is a word you can see in battle manga like Dragon Ball even if you're not familiar with judo.
Although it is not common to extend this phrase to someone's mental state, when someone clearly says 感情的な受け身 ("mental ukemi"), it figuratively refers to a technique to absorb mental shocks without panicking. This technique involves absorbing impact rather than dodging. 感情的な受け身も取れない implies that those who panic are still mentally untrained.
攻撃的な言動 is just a guess someone made in this question, where the questioner gave almost no context. They had to come up with a "shocking" situation where 受け身 might be used in non-physical contexts, hence 攻撃的な言動. Let's ignore that page and interpret 感情的な受け身 from the basic meaning of 受け身.
